# Tipos de registros repetidos em filtro

Tags: php, mysql, filtro

Tenho um formulário com um filtro de busca de serviços que pega as opções de uma coluna da minha tabela do banco de dados. 
O problema é que mais de uma pessoa presta o mesmo serviço, logo, mais tem mais de um registro com o mesmo serviço, o que faz com que o filtro tenha várias opções iguais.

Esse é o meu filtro de serviços:

```
<?php 
    require 'conexao.php';
    $queryServicos = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT servico FROM teste ORDER BY servico"); 
    $id           = $_POST["id"];
    $serv       = $_POST["servico"];

?>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <form action="teste-busca.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <span class="input-group-addon">Serviço:</i></span>
                          <select name="servico" id="servico" class="form-control">
                            <option>Selecione...</option>
                            <!-- PEGA OS SERVIÇOS DO BANCO DE DADOS E COLOCA NO OPTION -->
                                <?php while($serv = mysqli_fetch_array($queryServicos)) { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $serv['servico']; ?>"><?php echo $serv['servico']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                             -->
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Como eu faço pra aparecer somente um serviço de cada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na busca no banco de dados, você pode usar um DISTINCT para retornar valores diferentes.

Exemplo:

```
  "SELECT DISTINCT servico FROM teste ORDER BY servico"
```

Comment: Obrigada, resolveu o problema.

Comment: De nada, qualquer coisa só perguntar.